# cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken error when decrypting existing salt

Tags: python, encryption, base64, python-cryptography, fernet

### Preamble:

I did search StackOverflow and I know someone had a question like mine, but now (a couple months after first seeing it), I could not find that answer again. I'm fully aware there is likely a duplicate, but *for the life of me, I cannot find it in my searches.*

### The problem:

I have a cryptography module which generates a hashed password used for encrypting and decrypting secrets stored in a TinyDB database. All the functionality works except for decrypting the secret. The password is verifying correctly, so I know that isn't the issue. I am almost positive my issue is in getting the salt encoded properly in the decryption function.

#### Encryption code:

```py
        pas = use_password(args[0])
        salt = urandom(16)
        kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),length=32,salt=salt,iterations=100000,)
        sec = base64.b64encode(kdf.derive(bytes(pas,'utf-8')))
        token = Fernet(sec).encrypt(bytes(key,'utf-8'))
        salt = base64.b64encode(salt).decode('utf-8')
        return token, salt
```

#### Decryption:

```py
    pas = use_password(pw)
    ***salt = base64.b64decode(salt)***
    kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),length=32,salt=salt,iterations=100000,)
    sec = base64.b64encode(kdf.derive(bytes(pas,'utf-8')))
    # BUG: Reported defects -@ctrenthem at 7/26/2021, 8:07:00 PM: cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken error
    key = Fernet(sec).decrypt(bytes(token,'utf-8'))
    return key # Returns a byte object which may need to be converted to  a string.
```

#### What I tried:

I've already tried different variations of duplicating the salt encryption, but keep getting errors. Part of the problem is that [base64.encode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.encode) requires two "file objects" for input and output, and does not accept a string variable, which makes it unusable for my needs.

I could resolve this by creating a temp file, but that would be the worst solution because it involves

1. creating a new file in the filesystem with partially decrypted information, outside of RAM and the database, weakening the security of the whole system
2. Creates a new temp file, which is just a waste of system resources
3. Adds a whole lot more code just to implement something that I am positive can be implemented differently with one or two words.

Despite knowing that there is another solution, I cannot figure it out and am lost as to which base64 or bytes function will accomplish the job.

Comment: I can't find any problem when decrypting: https://replit.com/@3hK8cL8H24hwiS7/IllWastefulInternet

Comment: Actually, it was the encryption module that fixed it. Adding `token = token.decode('utf-8')` right before `salt = base64.b64encode(salt).decode('utf-8')` resolves the problem. Your repl helped me discover this. Thanks.